# PHP is not storing $_SESSION array values

Tags: php, ajax, session

I'm new in php and right now I'm having a problem when storing data in the `$_SESSION` array. I have an index page that retrieves information from an XML file and displays each product from the XML file in the page each one  with a button to add to a cart. When the button is pressed, I send an `XMLHttpRequest` with the id of the product I want to add to the `$_SESSION` array.

This is the main page:

```
function check_avi(id){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var available = this.responseText;
      if (available == "True") {
      alert("Add to the cart successfully.");
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, the car is not available now. Please try other cars.");
    }
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "add_delete_session.php?action=add&id="+id, true);
xhttp.send();
```

In the php I open the xml, retrieve the info and store it into an array, I then copy the information to the `$_SESSION[#number of product]`
What is happening is that after I add a product, it deletes in the session array the previous products, so each time I'm only having one product in the array and I want to store all of them to show them later in a shopping cart. The php should return a variable to the main page indicating the availability of the product but I'll do that later.

$arra is the array in where I'm storing the values obtained from the XML file corresponding to the product of the Id sent from the main page, like the price or name. $rf is the variable which count the amount of products stored and serve the same function as $_SESSION['g']

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_GET[id];
$action = $_GET[action];
if (empty($_SESSION['g'])) {
  $_SESSION['g'] = 0;
}
switch($action){
  case "add" :
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file("cars.xml");
    for ($e = 0; $e < 10; $e++) {
      $cont = 0;
      unset($arra);
      foreach ($xmlDoc->carrito[$e]->children() as $child) {
        $arra[$cont] = $child;
        $cont = $cont + 1;
      }
      if ($arra[0] == $id) {
        for ($f = 0; $f < 10; $f++) {
          $rf = $_SESSION['g'];
          $_SESSION[$rf][$f] = $arra[$f];
        }
        $_SESSION['g'] = $_SESSION['g'] + 1;
      }
    }
    break;
  case "delete":
    break;
}
```

If anyone could help me I'll be so grateful. 
Thanks

Comment: I think you need to make full array and then put it in session

Comment: I m not that sure but this doesnt looks ok `$_SESSION[$rf][$f]=$arra[$f];`

Answer (score 0):

I think your in your code

**1:**

```
if (empty($_SESSION['g'])) {
  $_SESSION['g'] = 0;
}
```

Actually here you haven't even defined the session at all and you are checking for its value if empty or not that's gonna stop execution of your code there itself, first you need to define the session variable and the check the value for it.

**2:**

```
$rf = $_SESSION['g'];
$_SESSION[$rf][$f] = $arra[$f];
```

Because it means that

```
$_SESSION[$_SESSION['g']][$f] =  $arra[$f];
```

Which is a wrong approach.
Better way first you make all the simplifications and then assign it to the `$_SESSION[]` and echo it.

Comment: What I'm thinking is, for example
If it's the first product then

`$_SESSION[0][1] =  "toyota";
$_SESSION[0][2] =  "Model2013";`

And for the second product

`$_SESSION[1][1] =  "mazda";
$_SESSION[1][2] =  "Model2015";`

It is wrong?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: just try echoing the result sesion at the end of your code and see what it results in .

Comment: And before that please define the session variavle your code is stopping execution there

Comment: Hi, but if I define the variable  `$_SESSION['g']` at the start, everytime I call the php, it will be reseted, doesn't it? And I need that value to know how many products I have stored or if it is the first one

Comment: then just define it in for loop and your job's done as `for(){$_SESSION['$i']}`. instead of g